# Advanced open and close animation for a button

Tags: python, kivy

The animation I currently have for opening and closing a button, is simply a sub button comes out from the main button and expands using size_hint. This animation simply enlarges the sublayout. I would like to 'unveil' the sublayout instead. What I mean by that, is to not mess with size_hint of the sub and instead of expanding itself, I want it to 'unveil' itself which makes for a much cleaner animation. Heres a link of a button animation that uses the same effect. https://codemyui.com/button-to-a-list-animation/.
In the linked animation, the bottom border goes down and reveals the list underneath, the same effect I want.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.graphics import *
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.behaviors import *
from kivy.properties import *

Builder.load_string("""
<Root>
    Button1:
        size_hint: 0.2,0.1
        pos_hint: {'top':0.9,'center_x':0.5}
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: [0.4,0.4,0.4,1]
            Rectangle
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        SubLayout:
            pos_hint: {'top':1,'center_x':0.5}
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: [0.7,0.7,0.7,1]
                Rectangle
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
                Color:
                    rgba: [1,1,1,1]
                Ellipse: 
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
""")


class Root(FloatLayout):
    pass


class Button1(ToggleButtonBehavior, FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Button1,self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_state(self, *args):
        if self.state == 'down':
            anim = Animation(pos_hint={'top':0},d=0.2)
            anim += Animation(size_hint=(2,2),d=0.2) #: expanding sublayout, how do I unveil instead?
            anim.start(self.children[0])
        else:
            anim = Animation(size_hint=(1,1),d=0.2)
            anim += Animation(pos_hint={'top':1},d=0.2)
            anim.start(self.children[0])


class SubLayout(FloatLayout):
    pass


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Root()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

As you can see, SubLayout expands and you can see the ellipse inside expanding with the button. What I would like is for the borders to move away, revealing whats underneath them while leaving the ellipse's size the same, which is the 'unveiling' effect. Any ideas on how to do this would be appreciated. Maybe something to do with an Fbo?

Comment: Thee link you included looks a lot like a `kivy.uix.dropdown`. Is that not what you are looking for?

Comment: Not exactly, kivy.uix.dropdown has no animation, the list simply appears.

Comment: I think you could use a `StencilView`, and animate its size/pos properties.

Comment: Yes that seems like the way to go, any idea of how I can code this?

Comment: Figured it out :D, had to change SubLayout to StencilView and add a FloatLayout with the contents as a child of Sub. Then had to give the FloatLayout pos and size relative to Button1 (can't make it relative to SubLayout as Sub will be moving around). Then the same animation to SubLayout gives me the affect I've been looking for. Thank you!